# BIM 360 viewer for all users without custom integration

Tags: node.js, autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360, autodesk-data-management

How and can I build a forge (basic BIM 360 viewing app) for all BIM 360 users without enabling application provisioning for each of the users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom integration of BIM360 only requires web application of Forge to provision with the BIM360 account, i.e. only the API developer creates Forge app, gets Forge client id, and ask BIM360 account to approve the id to the account (to complete provisioning).  As to BIM360 end users, they only need to use the web application. The application will setup authorization workflow to ask the end-user to login to authorize the web application to access their data in BIM360.

It does not mean every end-user also needs to create Forge client app, and provision the app with BIM360 account,

I’d also suggest you check the tutorial. It might help to understand the steps of building BIM360 application
https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/viewhubmodels

Comment: Thank you Sir, I basically wanted to understand provisioning of BIM 360 viewer for all users, without me enabling the viewer for each user. like in this application -https://bim360reports.autodesk.io/

Comment: as mentioned, any web application of BIM360 must be provisioned with BIM360 account.  Once it is provisioned, any account members of this BIM360 account (end-user) can use this application (following their permissions on the account/project), e.g. the end user might have access to one project, but not another,

Comment: when you produce your own application, the logic is same. the account integrate with your application This is topmost step. That is important to the data security.